# Custom function returns error when using lapply in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list that I'm passing to a function. This function works if I manually loop through this list. But when I use lapply I see this error:

```
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used[[1]]
```

Here's my sample code

````
columns_to_collapse <- list(c(
                         "abc",
                         "bcd",
                         "cde"))
                         
merge_cols <- function(cn) {
  # return column indices
  cn <- eval(cn)
  x <- d[, grep(cn, names(d))]
  x_1 <- as.numeric(x[1])
  x_2 <- as.numeric(x[2])
  # create a new column
  d[, substitute(cn) := do.call(paste, .SD), .SDcols = c(x_1,x_2)]
  # delete the old ones
  d[, (c(x_1,x_2)) := NULL]
  return(d)

}

lapply(columns_to_collapse, merge_cols)```
````

Comment: Try with `list("abc",  "bcd","cde")`. Using `list(c(...))` you create a list with one component which is a character vector of length 3. That's why you get the warning `argument 'pattern' has length > 1`. But just a guess as I could not run your code because `d` is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to loop through each element "abc", "bcd" and "cde" in the function. In that case you should pass either `c("abc", "bcd", "cde")` or `list("abc", "bcd", "cde")` but not a mixture of `list(c(..)` to lapply.

In your formulation, the lapply is running the function on each element of the list - your list has only 1 element which is a vector of 3 chars, and grep doesn't take vectors arguments, hence you are getting an error saying the `length is > 1`

I couldn't reproduce your code since you did not specify what `d` is in your code above

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.